# Possible to create a list of the last 12 months using LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
        List<DateTime> last12 = new List<DateTime>(12);
        last12.ForEach(t=>t.AddMonths(-{t.Index}));
```

But haven't quite figured out how to do the `{t.Index}` part...

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 DateTime start = DateTime.Now; 
 List<DateTime> last12 = (from r in Enumerable.Range(1,12) select start.AddMonths(0-r)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! You save my day. I actually need this function for the next 12 months but anyway you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want the current month counted are not, but this will point you in the right direction which you can edit accordingly for your needs.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime currentMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var lastTwelveMonths = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
              .Select(i => -i)
              .Select(monthsToAdd => currentMonth.AddMonths(monthsToAdd))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: this is definetely excessive `.Select(i => -i)`

Comment: Could you just drop the `.Select(i=>-i)` and use `Select(monthsToAdd => currentMonth.AddMonths(-monthsToAdd))` instead?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: Yes, you absolutely can, but then `monthsToAdd` isn't named appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach is tecnically not a Linq-method. It exists as a concrete method in the List class, but not in any interface.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(n => now.AddMonths(-n));

foreach (var month in months)
{
   Console.WriteLine(month.ToString("MMMM"));
}
```

Produces (in danish)

```
november
oktober
september
august
juli
juni
maj
april
marts
februar
januar
december
```

Comment: Your code has a nasty bug that won't surface in your unit testing unless you are very careful but will eventually kill you. You can get into trouble with `DateTime.Now`. Imagine it is `new DateTime(2010, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999)` when this statement starts executing and it takes more than one millisecond to execute.

Comment: @Jason so true, updated the code to make a local copy of DateTime.Now :)